# spark redis key column mapping not working - null returned

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, redis, key

I am following the example from spark-redis connector documentation to create Dataframes from a an existing hash.

The hash built as follows:

> 127.0.0.1:6379> hset person:1 name John age 30
>
> (integer) 2
>
> 127.0.0.1:6379> hset person:2 name Peter age 45
>
> (integer) 2
>
> 127.0.0.1:6379> hset person:3 name James age 40

The code to read the hash is as follows -

```
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .appName("MyApp")
        .master("local[*]")
        .config("spark.redis.host", "localhost")
        .config("spark.redis.port", "6379")
         .getOrCreate();
    Dataset<Row> df = spark.read()
       .format("org.apache.spark.sql.redis")
       .schema(new StructType(new StructField[] {
            DataTypes.createStructField("id", DataTypes.StringType, true),
            DataTypes.createStructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, false),
            DataTypes.createStructField("age", DataTypes.IntegerType, false)
       })
    )
    .option("keys.pattern", "person:*")
    .option("key.column", "id")
    .load();

    df.show();
    df.printSchema();
```

Output

```
+----+-----+---+
|  id| name|age|
+----+-----+---+
|null| John| 30|
|null|James| 40|
|null|Peter| 45|
+----+-----+---+

root
    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
    |-- name: string (nullable = false)
    |-- age: integer (nullable = false)
```

I was expecting 1, 2, 3 respectively in the Id column, but get null instead. Any pointers in this regard will help. Also this code is in Java so I am not sure if there an issue with data types.

Comment: Can you check whether the data type for id should be `Integer` in the schema : `DataTypes.createStructField("id", DataTypes.IntegerType, true)` instead of `StringType`

Comment: When I use IntegerType I still get null. When I set nullable parameter to false, I get a NPE for StringType and 0 for IntegerType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version you're using doesn't support it - use the master tip until a new version is released.

xref: https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis/issues/114